# How to make Window Height adjust to content?

Tags: c#, wpf, window, height

I have simple Window.
In this Window I have Grid with few Rows which height I am setting dynamicly.
Now I want to make `Window.Height = sum of Grids Rows.`
What a problem seems to be is that Grid itself is filling whole Window (it is ok) but in this grid there is empty space beside area occupied by rows.
What should I do?

For example I have rows witch height= 100 and 200 and whole grid have height 500 but should have 300.

Answer (score 8):

```
<Window
...
SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
  <Grid>
  ...
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

SizeToContent is the property that you want to set. I use this all of the time, it is great.

Comment: This worked for me. Also, other options are explained in more detail in the MSDN docs page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.sizetocontent.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Set [Window.SizeToContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.sizetocontent.aspx) property to WidthAndHeight.